# How to use Sitecore API to return result which removes Solr stopwords?

Tags: solr

In Solr GUI I am seeing that when I am in the  analyzer tab, it is removing stop words and returning results. But when I try to retrieve same result using the Sitecore search API it is not removing stop words and returning results. 
Could someone please assist me in how I can return results with Sitecore api which removes stop words?

here is my api call:

```
ISearchIndex searchIndex = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(IndexName);
IProviderSearchContext searchContext = searchIndex.CreateSearchContext();
filteredItem = searchContext.GetQueryable<SearchResult>();
```

Comment: We need more information on your setup; specifically how your indexes have been set up and what your API calls look like. Please refer to http://meta.sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/136/what-makes-a-good-post

Comment: Hi Mark,I have added api call to my post.

Comment: Is this a custom index that you've added?

Comment: Hi Pete,No it is Sitecore_Web_Index

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are asking for is not really supported by Solr. The fields you return from (defined by the `fl` parameter - automatically calculated by Sitecore) define to Solr that you want the field value (retrieved from the stored fields in Solr) - which is the original value.

I have not tried to retrieve an unstored field - that might return the post-analysis field value - but I don't think so.
you might get by using the analysis API (just like the admin does) - but from a performance perspective it might not be good.

I cannot imagine what the use case actually is? maybe highlighting might help you get something useful - but I am not sure what use case for this is.